# react-grid-layout Error: <DraggableCore> not mounted on DragStart

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

When attempting to drag around or resize any panel within my ResponsiveGridLayout i'm getting the following error:`<DraggableCore> not mounted on DragStart!`

Here is my GridLayout:

```
<ResponsiveGridLayout
        className="layout"
        cols={{ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
        onLayoutChange={(layout, allLayouts) => handleLayoutChange(allLayouts)}
        rowHeight={30}
        layouts={layouts}
        measureBeforeMount={false}
        compactionType="vertical"
        useCSSTransforms={true}
    >
        <Panel key="a" title="Interactions per country">
            <PieGraph />
        </Panel>
    </ResponsiveGridLayout>
```

Here is each individual Panel:

```
export const Panel: React.FC<IPanelProps> = (props) => {
const {className, children, title, shouldScroll, ...defaultPanelProps} = props;
let scrollClass = shouldScroll ? " scroll-y" : "";

return (
    <div {...defaultPanelProps} className={`custom-panel wrapper ${className}`} >
            {title && <div className="custom-panel-title text-medium">{title}</div>}

            <div className={`custom-panel-content ${scrollClass}`} onMouseDown={ e => e.stopPropagation() }>
                {children}
            </div>
    </div>
);
```

};

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by adding a "ref" to my custom `<Panel/>` Component. This error only seems to happen if you have your own component (instead of a div with a key) inside your react-grid-layout.

To create the ref simply do `const ref = React.createRef()` and pass it to your Custom Panel component like so:

```
<ResponsiveGridLayout
        className="layout"
        cols={{ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
        onLayoutChange={(layout, allLayouts) => handleLayoutChange(allLayouts)}
        rowHeight={30}
        layouts={layouts}
        measureBeforeMount={false}
        compactionType="vertical"
        useCSSTransforms={true}
    >
        <Panel ref={ref} key="a" title="Liters per active country">
            <PieGraph />
        </Panel>
    </ResponsiveGridLayout>
```

And your custom Panel becomes:

```
export const Panel = React.forwardRef((props: IPanelProps, ref) => {
const { className, children, title, shouldScroll, ...defaultPanelProps } = props as any;
let scrollClass = shouldScroll ? " scroll-y" : "";

return (
    <div ref={ref} {...defaultPanelProps} className={`custom-panel wrapper ${className}`} >

        {title && <div className="custom-panel-title text-medium">{title}</div>}

        <div className={`custom-panel-content ${scrollClass}`} onMouseDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
            {children}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

});

Notice the `React.forwardRef((props: IPanelProps, ref)` and the prop for `ref={ref}`.

Comment: hey i can u create a sandbox or something like that as im not able to get where u using createref()

Comment: type of Panel div should be different from div. how forwarding ref is working? tslint shows an error because of this.